# Android dynamic slide menu

Tags: android, menu

I am new in Android. I want to create a slide menu when clicking a button. I checked many questions in this form. But every answer need a menu items in XML file. But in my case i want a dynamic menu. If anyone have a solution, please share here

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can begin to find how to construct your menu in XML, and after begin to add XML elements by a loop or something to add your XML elements programatically, with inflate you can construct all that you construct only with XML.

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Or use a listView with an adapter
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html